# Excell pivot table without any calculations (vba is allowed)

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

How can I create pivot table using macro and save in my data as is? I don't want use any of summarize functions.
The problem is that the data is not only the numbers but also the strings.
Example:

```
    Data table:
userCol| question| ansVar| userAnswer
    1   question1 var1     1
    1   question2 var1     1
    1   question3 usr_var 'blah'
    2   question1 var2     1
    2   question2 usr_var 'koko'
    2   question3 usr_var 'meow'

Pivot table:   
        xxx|question1        |question2   |question3
           |var1 var2 usr_var|var1 usr_var|usr_var 
        1    1                  1           'blah'
        2         1                'koko'   'meow'
```

Where userCol is rowField, question and ansVar is colFields and userAnswer is data for PivotTable.

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: You can't have text strings in the data field of a pivot table. You will need to write VBA to re-arrange this data. I would suggest adding question ID's and ansVar ID's which you can use to sort the headings.